# I'd like to talk about Korean drinking culture and I'd like to know which sentences are possible

Tags: sentence-construction

I'd like to talk about Korean drinking culture. So,

First, Koreans drink a lot. There's a research saying that Korea is the country who consumes more alcohol than any other country does.

> 1. And another feature that Korea has regarding how to drink is that...
> 2. And another characteristic that Korea has about drinking culture is that...
> 3. And another characteristic of Korean drinking culture is that...
> 4. And another side of Korean drinking culture is that...

...we usually drink sitting on a chair, not like other countries where many people drink standing or moving.

Which one is the one that I can use?

Comment: 3. goes smoothly with the rest of the sentence.

Comment: you mean I can use 124 as well?

Comment: 1.: "Feature" sounds strange IMHO, 2. is too cumbersome (3. says the same as 2. but more to the point), 4. is so-so, it works, but mhm, sounds, well, I don't know.

Comment: While this is not the focus of the question, you generally don't "spend" alcohol. You might spend (money) on alcohol or you may consume alcohol. Which of these it should be depends on what the statistic actually showed.

Comment: I fixed a few typos, but you still need to heed @DRF's advice and adjust the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to sound idiomatic, #3 or #4 will do.   #1 and #2 have no egregious grammatical errors but they are not quite idiomatic. Let's invert the sentences to see why:

> And another feature that Korea has regarding how to drink is that...
>   And another characteristic that Korea has about drinking culture is
>   that...

Korea has another feature regarding how to drink.
Korea has another characteristic about drinking culture.

The phrases "feature regarding how" and "characteristic about" are the core problems here.  *Feature* and *characteristic* are synonymous with "property", and a property is *inherent*, so we need **of**, not **about** or **regarding**.

**... feature|characteristic *of* Korean drinking culture is ....**

Also, making Korea the subject of a relative clause is verbose:

> ...another characteristic *that Korea has about drinking culture* ... is

You could make *that Korea has* an adjective:

**Another characteristic of {*Korean* drinking culture} is...**

or a prepositional phrase:

**Another characteristic of {drinking culture *in Korea*} is...**